# How to send data from one view to another, it is the make,model, etc. It is not a form

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

This is the Car Model:

```
public partial class Car
{

    public int CarID { get; set; }
    public string Make { get; set; }
    public string Model { get; set; }
    public string Colour { get; set; }
    public bool Availability { get; set; }
    public double Mileage { get; set; }
    public string RegNumber { get; set; }
    public string EngineSize { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> LateFeeHourly { get; set; }
    public int CarCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string OutOnRent { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath2 { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath3 { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath4 { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath5 { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath6 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<decimal> DailyFee { get; set; }
    public string Transmission { get; set; }
}
```

This is the Car category model:

```
public partial class CarCategory
{
    public int CarCategoryID { get; set; }
    public string CarCategoryName { get; set; }
    public int NoOfSeat { get; set; }
}
```

Viewmodel:

```
public class CarVM
{
    public List<Car> Cars { get; set; }
    public List<CarCategory> CarCats { get; set; }
}
```

View:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.Cars)
{
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <div class="carGalleryWrapper">
            <div class="carGallery" style="background:url('@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem=>item.ImagePath)') no-repeat 0 0 ">
                <div class="carDetails">
                    <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyFee) / Per Day</h4>
                    <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model), Navi, Leather, ABS</h3>
                    <button type="submit" class="driveMore">Drive Now</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

}
```

When the user clicks on drive now button it goes to details view which has the specific details of the car. But I can't seem to figure out how to do it.

Comment: Do you have Detail action in controller?So just use `@Html.ActionLink("Detail","Detail", new { id=item.CarID })`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could send your data via url parameters and use GET on your controller action.

[Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.actionlink?view=aspnet-mvc-5.2#System_Web_Mvc_Html_LinkExtensions_ActionLink_System_Web_Mvc_HtmlHelper_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Object_System_Object_)

Pass multiple parameters

```
@Html.ActionLink("Drive Now","actionName","controllerName", new{ @make=item.Make, @model = item.Model }, new { });
```

or simply the car Id

```
@Html.ActionLink("Drive Now","actionName","controllerName", new{ @id = item.CarID }, new { });
```

Full code;

```
<div class="carDetails">
   <h4>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DailyFee) / Per Day</h4>
   <h3>@Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Make) @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Model), Navi, Leather, ABS</h3>
   @Html.ActionLink("Drive Now","actionName","controllerName", new{ @make=item.Make, @model = item.Model }, new { });
</div>
```

Then in your target controller action, simply catch those values being passed by adding parameters.

```
public ActionResult actionName(string make, string model){

}
```

or

```
public ActionResult actionName(int id){
   var car = db.Cars.FirstOrDefault(c=>c.CarId == id);
   // car.Make
   // car.Model
}
```

Comment: Thanks alot, this really helped but there when i go to details page, it is still not showing me the data.. @Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Model) i tried to display it like this.

Comment: @TabishRiaz please include your 1) Details controller action method and 2) view.

Comment: Thanks man, it wasn't showing because i forgot to return the car. Again, thankyou very much.